# Proving existence of a triangle of area $\leq \frac{1}{8}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

**Problem:** Given any set $S$ of $9$ points within a unit square, show that there always exist $3$ distinct points in $S$ such that the area of the triangle formed by these $3$ points is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{8}$

I am supposed to do this using the pigeonhole principle. I used the usual technique of partitioning the square to conclude that there is a triangle with area less than $\frac{1}{4}$ but I am unable to improve the bound.

Please help.

Comment: You need a sharper estimate of the area of the largest triangle  in a $0.5\times 0.5$ square.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ooh! got it. got it. thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First divide the unit square into four squares with sides $s$ of length $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now given $9$ points and $4$ squares, by the pigeon hole principle at least one square $S$ which contains three of those points. Those three points form a triangle whose area $A$ is bounded by half the area of $S$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173346/188658) for a proof). Since the sides $s$ of $S$ have length $\frac{1}{2}$, we have that $$ A\leq \frac{1}{2}s^2= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$$