# Largest equilateral triangle which fits inside a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization

What is the area of the largest equilateral triangle which fits inside a square of side a?

so area of trinagle is $\frac{a^2}{2}$, however it is wrong, why ?

Comment: That's not an equilateral triangle, for one thing.

Comment: The largest triangle is indeed half the area of the square.  But the largest equilateral triangle will be something smaller than that.

Comment: just get a piece of paper and draw a few pictures. This is a very visual problem.

Comment: You shouldn't consider the height and the base to be equal, that is why the area isn't $\frac{a^2}{2}$

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028600) provides an answer for triangles in general.

Comment: @Arnaldo this is the question

Comment: @arnaldo i drew the same thing as below however i do not know hwo to proceed

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Place one vertex of the triangle on one of the corners of the square, and the other two vertices symmetrically placed on the opposite neighbouring sides of the square

Comment: ok what do i do after????????

Comment: what do i do do do

Comment: Lanel the side of the triangle $x$ and use some basic trigonometry and Pythagoras to make an equation for $x$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

123456789012345678901234567890