# Approximating $(n+1)$-gon with $n$-gon

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Given a convex $(n+1)$-gon $A$, I want to find the convex $n$-gon $B$ of smallest area that contains $A$. Specifically, I want a bound on the area of $B$. I can work out specific examples, but have no idea on how to tackle the general case (I am hoping that someone can point me towards some research, if it exists).  [this code golf post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/digesting-polygons) explains the same problem (except I only care about convex polygons).

[This stack exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028600/smallest-possible-triangle-to-contain-a-square)  gives an answer in the case of a square.

Intuitively, in the case where there is a very small side length (relatively), it seems like the adjacent sides can be "extended" outside of $A$ until they intersect (assuming the adjacent angles are obtuse).

**Edit:** let's assume that $diam(A) < N$ for some constant $N$.